# Unable to save file type in server using Apache fileupload library

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm just trying to upload any file using type=file in jsp and then trying to save in server using Servlet.

Servlet code in doPost method is as below

```
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    System.out.println(" isMultipart ="+isMultipart);
    if (isMultipart) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
           System.out.println(" inside iterator..is form field"+item.isFormField());




                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = item.getName();

                    System.out.println(" inside nor form field");
                    String root1 = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

                    System.out.println(" server root ="+root1);
                    File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
                    if (!path.exists()) {
                        boolean status = path.mkdirs();

                        System.out.println(" inside path doesnt exist");
                    } // if file path doesnt exists

                    File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                    System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                } // if condition for field not form field but file
            } // while more files per request
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

On line  `if (!item.isFormField())`  Its not going inside. Even in jsp i had put proper enctype as below

```
<form action="Test" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<label for="fil">Please select file</label>
<input id="fil" type="file">
<input type="submit" name="click" value="click">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved. After putting name attribute like this `<input id="fil" type="file" name="file" >` the problem was resolved.